# Configure PHP CodeSniffer to fix code on the fly in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I have PhpStorm 10 and want to setup php Code Sniffer to automatically correct me code. This article https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Code+Sniffer+in+PhpStorm points to "Project Settings | Code Style" and I cannot even find that. I have File | Edit | View | Navigate | Code | Refactor | Run | Tools | VCS | Window | Help at the top and have no idea where to find project settings. I do have File > Settings but cannot figure it out.

My project is a web portal built in Symfony. I saw a colleague run Atom and when he saves a file it is code-fixed on the fly - that is what I want. Help please.

Comment: *"... points to "Project Settings | Code Style" and I cannot even find that."* Look at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`. Hint: Settings screen has search field -- try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm does not support code fixing on the fly with Code Sniffer.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25815 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

Right now, if you wish you may create an [External Tools entry](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) for that and run it manually when needed.

Comment: Really sucks that PHPStorm does not have this built in?

Answer (score 0):

Find this from web (how to config the external tools)

> https://thiagoponte.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/run-php-codesniffer-code-beautifier-and-fixer-from-phpstorm/

[image]